# Java library for error-correction

Tags: library, java

I am looking for a simple error-correction library in Java.

It needs to be able to correct some errors in variable-length messages. However, the error-correcting codes together with the message must have a fixed-length (for transmission).

Mathematical complexity or time to decode isn't a concern.

Edit:
I am transmitting data over sound. The errors that usually occur are single bit-errors but sometimes also larger bursts. Shifting of the entire message and Erasure of bits are not an issue.

Comment: What kind of errors? Could you expand on your exact requirements?

Comment: Okay, I expanded the question.

Answer (score 1):

This one is excellent. Fast and extremely flexible in that you can use pretty much any combination of data/parity blocks you want.

https://www.backblaze.com/open-source-reed-solomon.html